# Optimising Java Code base for Android for round price to 0.99 cents including tax

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, java-8

The idea is to have a function that finds the correct price to use that includes tax so that the price ends with a .99 at the end for example if the cost is $1.33, the final price should end with $1.99 that includes tax.
So the code shown works very well in native java, but to implement in Android java gives memory errors even if I run this on a background thread using RxJava for Android.

So here is the Java code I used in android as well :

```
public class Main {
    static  int counts = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        System.out.println("Price to use : " + findPriceToCharge99(Double.parseDouble("0.05" ) , .15 ) + "  :::counts "+counts);
    }

    public static double roundDecimalPlaces(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

    static double findPriceToCharge99(double price,double taxVal){
        price= roundDecimalPlaces(price ,2);
        double taxAmount = (price)  * taxVal ;
        counts++;
        String check = roundDecimalPlaces((price + taxAmount),2)+"";
        return  check.split("\\.")[1].equals("99") ? price : findPriceToCharge99(price+.01 ,taxVal);
    }
}
```

Here is my stack trace :

```java
2021-03-12 08:27:40.288 18794-19179/com.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
    Process: com.app, PID: 18794
    io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1039KB
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1039KB
        at java.lang.ref.PhantomReference.<init>(PhantomReference.java:80)
        at sun.misc.Cleaner.<init>(Cleaner.java:115)
        at sun.misc.Cleaner.create(Cleaner.java:133)
        at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:242)
        at java.math.BigInt.makeValid(BigInt.java:48)
        at java.math.BigInt.putULongInt(BigInt.java:83)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:105)
        at java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(BigInteger.java:375)
        at java.math.BigDecimal.getUnscaledValue(BigDecimal.java:2946)
        at java.math.BigDecimal.doubleValue(BigDecimal.java:2552)
```

Comment: Q: What is the exact error message?  Q: Exactly what line does the error occur on?  You can determine both in your IDE's debugger (e.g. Android Studio).  Please update your post with the answers.

Comment: @paulsm4 i have update the details of the error

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i have also converted this to a javascript version, this is also causing errors : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded .yes it should work but the recession seems to be demanding .

Comment: Looks like you're exceeding the stack size on Android. I ran your example on the desktop and there was a recursion that went 82 levels deep. So yeah, find a way to increase the thread stack size on Android, or optimize your code. There should be absolutely no need for recursion to implement your requirement.

Comment: @kinsley kajiva - thank you for adding the error message!  I'm sorry the question was "closed" before you did this.  PROBLEM: stack overflow, because of "infinite recursion".   SOLUTION: Don't check for "99" exactly.  Floating point arithmetic only gives you an *APPROXIMATE* value.  You need to check for "98.99999" as well as "100.0000001", for example.  Sorry I'm not able to give you a full "reply" (because your post was closed); I hope that helps (at least a little).

Answer (score 0):

for future researchers

```
int price = 99 ;
float x = Float.valueOf(price) / 100 ;
```

```
Result : 0.99
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.